# My Android simple Interest Calculator keeps crashing

Tags: android, calculator

public class Simple_Interest extends Activity {

```
EditText p, r, t, e, si;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_interest);
    p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtprinci);
    r = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtrate);
    p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtyear);
    si = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtres);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butint);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double n1 = 0;
            double n2 = 0;
            double n3 = 0;
            double ans = 0;
            n1 = Double.parseDouble(p.getText().toString());
            n2 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
            n1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
            ans = (n1 * n2 * n3) / 100;
            si.setText(Double.toString(ans));
        }

    });
}
```

}

Every time i try to run the program in emulator, i get the error dialog called "unfortunately application has stopped working"....

need help....

Comment: LogCat error is  java.lang.numberFormatexception: Invalid double:""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a mistake :

```
p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtprinci);
r = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtrate);
p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtyear);
```

you have 2 times p and no t

```
p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtprinci);
r = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtrate);
t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtyear);
```

should be better otherwise t is never initialised

same for

```
        n1 = Double.parseDouble(p.getText().toString());
        n2 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
        n1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
```

you need to change the last one to

```
        n3 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
```

your onclick should be something like :

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        double n1 = 0;
        double n2 = 0;
        double n3 = 0;
        double ans = 0;

        if( !p.getText().toString().equals("") && !r.getText().toString().equals("") &&!t.getText().toString().equals("") )
        {
        n1 = Double.parseDouble(p.getText().toString());
        n2 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
        n1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
        ans = (n1 * n2 * n3) / 100;
        si.setText(Double.toString(ans));
        }
        else{
        si.setText("Missing data");
        }
    }
```

Or even better with try and catch ;)

Ps: you initialize the variable e but you never use it :)

Comment: This is what happens when you're too economic with variable names..